# Xctest how to know test cases pass/fail before suit finished so that i can update test cycle when ever test finished

Tags: xctest, xctestcase

override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

```
    continueAfterFailure = false
```

XCTestObservationCenter.shared.addTestObserver(observer)

```
    XCUIApplication().launch()
    let observer = Observer() // your created observer class
    let observationCenter = XCTestObservationCenter.shared
    observationCenter.addTestObserver(observer)

}

override func tearDown() {

    super.tearDown()
```

And below is the observer class
but nothing is prinitng

i want the test case id and status of each test case finished running so that i will update status in Jira or Zephyr

class Observer: NSObject, XCTestObservation {
    var failedTC = 0

```
func testBundleWillStart(_ testBundle: Bundle) {
    print("test Bundle Started")
}

func testBundleDidFinish(_ testBundle: Bundle) {
    print("test Bundle Finished")
}

func testSuiteWillStart(_ testSuite: XCTestSuite) {
    print("test Suite Started")
}

func testSuiteDidFinish(_ testSuite: XCTestSuite) {
    print("test Bundle Ended")
}

private func testSuite(_ testSuite: XCTestSuite, didFailWithDescription description: String, inFile filePath: String?, atLine lineNumber: UInt) {
    print("test Suit failed information" + description)
}

func testCaseWillStart(_ testCase: XCTestCase) {
    print("test case Started")
}

func testCaseDidFinish(_ testCase: XCTestCase) {
    print("test case Finished")
}

private func testCase(_ testCase: XCTestCase, didFailWithDescription description: String, inFile filePath: String?, atLine lineNumber: UInt) {
    print("test case failed message" + description)

    var tmpMsgArr = description.components(separatedBy: ".---")
    let testcaseID = tmpMsgArr[1]

    print("------" + testcaseID)

   // yourmethodThatwillbeCalledWhenTCFail() // implement this method that you want to execute

    failedTC += 1
}
```

}